# HTML5 Layout DIV sizings

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on amending a HTML5 template. The default setup of the Bootstrap parameters were:

- col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4
- col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8

This meant that the latin text took up 20% of screen width and pics 80%, but I want it the other way round... Text taking up 80% width, photo 20%.

Can someone please advise what the bootstrap parameters need to be for this for responsive to work? I've tried loads of options but can't get it right!

Is this possible or do I need to revise CSS?

Thanks

Full code below:

```
<section id="ourteam" class="wow fadeInUp">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <h2>Meet our Team</h2>
      <div class="ourteamd">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit eros. Pellentesque nec vulpe eros.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
      <div class="responsive">
        <div> 
          <div class="third-effect">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/384x444" class="img-responsive" alt="Our Team">
            <div class="mask">
                <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                <a href="#" class="twitter">Twitter</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: You just need to switch the content inside the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch the size value of both columns, 4 becomes 8, and 8 becomes 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
  <h2>Meet our Team</h2>
  <div class="ourteamd">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit eros. Pellentesque nec vulpe eros.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="responsive">
        <div class="third-effect">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/384x444" class="img-responsive" alt="Our Team">
            <div class="mask">
                <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                <a href="#" class="twitter">Twitter</a>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```